# how to insert specific string according to specific number in php?

Tags: php

i have a situation that need to insert specific string according to specific number. for example the number is 4 and i need 4 of specific string (in this case is `'?'` ) like this: number 5 so `$str = '?????'`.
in another word i have a array like this `['first item','second item', 'third item']` . i need to count items in this array, that can accomplished by `count()` and according to that number insert `?` . so the final string should be `'?,?,?'` with `','` as separator.

Comment: Take a look at [`str_repeat()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-repeat.php)

Comment: For the second one you can use `array_fill()` and `implode()`